# How to filter out invalid patterns in square-like binary signals?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, bigdata, signal-processing

I am working with a dataset that contains a binary signal similar to the one depicted in the plot below. The goal is to develop a data cleaning function to eliminate incomplete square patterns within the signals, as exemplified by the shaded box. (Note that the illustration serves primarily for visual clarity; the original signals exhibit irregularities in terms of the duration of each square and the time gaps between them.) The invalid cycles in the dataset are essentially due to missing points. Therefore, the invalid cycles will be the ones that deviate significantly from the square shape.

Example of binary signal with invalid cycles:

[image: Example of binary signal with invalid cycles]

One challenge in this data processing task is the dataset's sheer size, which may have tens of millions of rows. Thus, I have been researching signal processing libraries and vectorized approaches to circumvent the need for iterative loops. One approach I have explored involves calculating the gradient of the signal using NumPy to identify the start and end points of valid signals, those that form perfect square shapes. However, I am encountering difficulties in using this information to filter out the rows corresponding to the invalid signals from my dataframe. Another possibility might be using some sort of convolution, but I do not have much experience in this type of analysis.

I would greatly appreciate any insights, ideas, or tips from the community on how to tackle this problem effectively. Thanks!

Comment: Your goal is pretty ill-defined. What actually constitutes a good vs. bad pulse? Do very short gaps in the pulse matter - if so, how short? To what degree do the levels matter - is anything between e.g. 5% and 95% completely invalid for the purpose of pulse definition?

Comment: Is the ideal binary pulse always a square wave with constant frequency, amplitude and phase?

Comment: And what the data looks like?
Are they just a bunch of Amplitude, supposed to be evenly sampled in time? In which case, why not just count the number of values that are neither 0 nor 1?
Or are they a series of pairs t/amplitude (in which case the defect you exhibit does not mean that there are intermediate values from 0 to 1 in `amplitude`, but that there is a hole in `t`. And then, why not just find those holes in `t`)?

Comment: I am pretty sure that if it were that easy, you would have done it. But understand that with no code, no example data, no nothing, we cannot understand why those simple method couldn't work. And cannot know what other method we could think of could also not work. In other words, we are shooting in the dark.

Comment: @Reinderien, Sorry for the lack of clarity. I tried to use an illustration to indicate what an "invalid" pulse means. Basically, it is every pulse with a significant delay to start (or end). More precisely, if the time difference between the first point in the pulse maximum and the previous one is longer than the typical acquisition time for my sensor (~2 sec), I need to discard this pulse.

Comment: @Reinderien Regarding your second question, the answer is no. As I added in parenthesis, the plot is only for illustration purposes; the original signals exhibit irregularities in terms of the duration of each square and the time gaps between them.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at slopes between consecutive points.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible approaches is to use filtering based on wavelet transform. In this case, a convenient wavelet seems to be one of the [Haar wavelet](http://robotics.stanford.edu/%7Escohen/lect02/) family. In Python, the [PyWavelets](https://pywavelets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) package can be used for this purpose.
However, selecting the most suitable tool would require more details about the signal, preferably in the form of a sample signal.